# Why isn't current_account nil, after the session controller destroys it in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    # No need for anything in here, we are just going to render our
    # new.html.erb AKA the login page
  end

  def create
    # Look up User in db by the email address submitted to the login form and
    # convert to lowercase to match email in db in case they had caps lock on:
    account = Account.find_by(email: params[:login][:email].downcase)

    # Verify user exists in db and run has_secure_password's .authenticate()
    # method to see if the password submitted on the login form was correct:
    if account && account.authenticate(params[:login][:password])
      # Save the user.id in that user's session cookie:
      session[:account_id] = account.id.to_s
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      # if email or password incorrect, re-render login page:
      flash.now.alert = "Incorrect email or password, try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # delete the saved account_id key/value from the session:
    session.delete(:account_id)

    redirect_to login_path, notice: "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

and an application controller:

```
    require 'open3'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:destroy] 

  # Make the current_user method available to views also, not just controllers:
    helper_method :current_account

    # Define the current_user method:
    def current_account
      # Look up the current account based on account_id in the session cookie:
      if session[:account_id]
        @current_account = Account.find(session[:account_id])
      end
      #logger.debug("current_account: #{@current_account.attributes.inspect}")
    end

    # authorize method redirects user to login page if not logged in:
        def authorize
          redirect_to login_path, alert: 'You must be logged in to access this page.' if current_account.nil?
        end
end
```

and in the _header.html.erb, I have:

```
  <div id="account">
  <% if current_account %>
      <!-- current_user will return true if a user is logged in -->
        <%= "Logged in as #{current_account.email}" %> | <%= link_to 'Home', users_path %> | <%= link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete %>
      <% else %>
        <!-- not logged in -->
        <%= link_to 'Home', users_path %> | <%= link_to 'Log In', login_path %> or <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_account_path %>
      <% end %>
  </div><!-- #account -->
```

I click the logout link and I get the Login screen, BUT, the current_account.email is still displayed.  It appears that the session with key :account_id is not being destroyed.  How am I getting to the Login page, but am not logged out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite by accident, I found that if I changed

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

to

```
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:destroy]
```

in the application controller,

The problem cleared up.  Now, what did I do and are there any bad side effects?